# How do I activate the internet?

Tags: wifi, release-juno, internet, ethernet

I am connected to the network, but I can not open any page in the browser nor does it work in the App Center

I'm on Juno 5.0

Comment: Do you know how to add/change your DNS? If so, use Cloudflare's and Google's - `1.1.1.1` and `8.8.8.8`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried pinging a website to check whether you're really connected to Internet? You can do it via terminal:

```
ping google.com
```

Comment: to all the devices in the network, the internet works, except for me

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot your connection open the Terminal and use the [`ping`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ping) command as follows:

```
ping google.com
```

Please add the output to your question. If the ping is successful, you should see something like this:

```
$ ping google.com
PING google.com(ham04s01-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4005:80a::200e)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from ham04s01-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4005:80a::200e): icmp_seq=1 ttl=48 time=25.8 ms
64 bytes from ham04s01-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4005:80a::200e): icmp_seq=2 ttl=48 time=26.4 ms
```

This means your browser might be the problem. Instead of the default web browser, try to use Firefox or Chrome and check if the problem persists.

If the ping is *not* successful, try to [`ping`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ping) a well known IP adress like `1.1.1.1` or `8.8.8.8`

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

Please add the output to your question. If the ping is successful, you should see something like this:

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=25.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=50 time=26.6 ms
```

This probably means, there is a problem with DNS resolving. To confirm, try [`nslookup google.com`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nslookup) and add the output to your question.

If the ping is *not* successful, run the command [`ifconfig`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ifconfig) and add the output to your question, so we can try to troubleshoot further.